# Завершение программы при помощи ret

Tags: ассемблер, стек

Есть программа, которая считывает сама себя и перезаписывает свой код. Мне непонятны такие комментарии к ней: при загрузке COM-программы вершина стека устанавливается на предпоследний байт нашего сегмента, т. е. sp=0FFFEh. При выполнении команды "ближний call" sp уменьшается на 2, т. е. становится равным 0FFFCh. Это свидетельствует о том, что при вызове подпрограммы процессор заносит в стек адрес возврата. Поэтому и не происходит путаницы при работе: выходить ли в DOS или вернуться из процедуры. Так или иначе, выход в DOS командой ret в COM-программах происходит только в том случае, если sp=0FFFEh, и программа сама не затерла первые 2 байта по смещению 0000h (т. е. команду int 20h) того сегмента, куда она загрузилась изначально.

Сама программа:

```
CSEG segment
assume cs:CSEG, ds:CSEG, es:CSEG, ss:CSEG
org 100h

begin:
    mov dx, offset file_name
    call open_file
    jc error_file

    ;Открыли файл
    mov bx, ax
    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov cx, offset finish - 100h
    mov dx, offset begin
    int 21h

    ;Прочитали файл
    call close_file

    ;Выводим сообщение
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset mess_ok
    int 21h
    ret

    ;Не смогли найти файл
error_file:
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 7
    int 21h
    ret

    ;Процедуры
    ;Открытие файла
open_file proc
    cmp handle, 0FFFFh
    jne quit_open
    mov ax, 3D00h
    int 21h
    mov handle, ax
    ret
quit_open:
    stc
    ret
    handle dw 0FFFFh
open_file endp

close_file proc
    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, handle
    int 21h
    ret
close_file endp

;Данные
file_name db 'prog09.com', 0
mess_ok db 'All is ok!', 0Ah, 0Dh, '$'

finish equ $

CSEG ends
end begin
```

1) Непонятно, что такое "ближний call".

2) Механика работы ret. Если эта инструкция снимает со стека адрес возврата, стало быть, в DOS она всегда увеличивает регистр стека на 2?

3) Если последнее верно, то остается понять, как из FFFE получили 0000. Здесь вычисления, похожие на модулярную арифметику: n mod n = 0. Если бы мы увеличили регистр стека на 1, то из FFFE получилось бы FFFF mod FFFF = 0000. Но ret увеличивает указатель на два, и поэтому должно получиться 0001. Что я говорю не так?

И еще. Почему по смещению 0000 находится int 20h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в ассемблере есть понятия ближних и дальних переходов. Вызов call от них не отличается. Дальний переход(вызов) - это когда адрес указывается полностью (в данном случае и сегмент, и смещение в нем). А ближний (он же короткий) переход - это переход в пределах одного байта (до 128 назад или до 127 байт вперед).

`ret` работает просто - она снимает с стека адрес, который там сохранил вызов call (или пользователь своими ручками подложил, или операционная система все настроила правильно) и делает переход по этому адресу. Команда [ret](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#ret) также бывает ближней и дальней. И естественно, она должна быть парной к call.

Что же добавляется в стек? в случае дальнего вызова, туда добавляется содержимое регистров cs и ip (то есть, 4 байта). В случае короткого (ближнего) только ip (два байта).

и третий вопрос. Да, регистры 16 битные. И поэтому тут чистой воды "модулярная арифметика". Только модуль немного не угадали. Он равен 10000h. и в этом случае FFFEh + 0002h = 10000h == 0000h.

А вот [int 20](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0025.php) - это прерывания DOS (читай как "API DOS"), которое значит "заверши программу, которая его вызвала". А вот как так оказалось, что по заданному смещению находиться int 20 - это просто dos постаралась.

Comment: jmp на самом деле бывают 3х видов, а call только двух, http://looch-disasm.narod.ru/refe31.htm  И по тексту у вас выходит, как будто call бывает то же в пределах +-127, хотя позже в тексте и видно, что в стек он кладет ip целиком и переходит все таки куда угодно в пределах сегмента